# External reference not working

Tags: microsoft-excel

using CONCATENATE i wrote an external reference , but the value is not picking from the external file since the files are not getting linked to each other. INDIRECT() used but values are picking only if the excel file is opened. Is there any other solution.

Comment: Possibly, but without any example of your formula, data, expected output, etc. can't make any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `INDIRECT()` won't work with a closed file.

The traditional method of getting around that is to have some "out-of-the-way" place in your spreadsheet, or even a Named Range, where you have a pre-written DIRECT formula looking into the (sometime closed, sometimes open) other spreadsheet. You then reference that pre-written formula to provide the value you desire. If you build a reference and give it to `INDIRECT()` it would refer to that DIRECT formula in the same spreadsheet and the DIRECT formula would do the looking into a close spreadsheet that `INDIRECT()` cannot do.

If you have more than a couple possibilities, it could be a little obnoxious to set that up... Say you wanted to look at a given cell in 40 different spreadsheet. Only one of them in the cell you write the `INDIRECT()` formula, of course, at a time, but that one could be any of 40. You'd have to write the 40 DIRECT formulas and use a slightly different logic, an `IF()` test formula, in the place you need the value.

However, you can use standard string formulas to write those DIRECT formulas, leaving off the "=" at the beginning, using some character the rest of the formula won't use. Perhaps a "¢" character. So you get 40 "formulas" that look like:

```
¢A1
```

Then, when done, copy and paste as values, the use `Find and Replace` to replace that unusual character with the "=" and the strings will convert to formulas. So... obnoxious... but not hard or even really time-consuming.

Of course, if you have 40 workbooks to refer to and possibly a hundred different cells in each, that COULD get pretty tiresome... But at least the `IF()` tests to pick which of them to get the value from would be no harder, really.

But bear in mind, and this is a general thing for looking into possibly closed workbooks, there is a pretty heavy burden on Excel to do all that for each place it has to do it, compared to any usual demand you place on Excel. Evaluating a function in a formula is much easier than going out to Windows, opening the file in the background, loading it, finding the value, getting Windows to close it, and placing the value in the current workbook. Like running 40 macros at the same time, if one has 40 of these references.

It WILL do it though, and you never know if it will be noticeable until you try it yourself, then wait for your range of users to try it. So don't shy away from it for that reason alone, not without trying it first.